How to draw rainbow cairo linear gradient using rgb values from an array?
I'm trying to draw a Cairo rainbow gradient on a gtk drawing surface. To do this, the RGB color data will be stored in an array and from that array, the rainbow will be drawn. I tried some functions from this website but didn't get the expected result. The script and images are given below:
My expectation:

This is the script:
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

uint32_t rgb(double ratio)
{
    int normalized = (int)(ratio * 256 * 6);

    //find the region for this position
    int region = normalized / 256;

    //find the distance to the start of the closest region
    int x = normalized % 256;

    uint8_t r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    switch (region)
    {
    case 0: r = 255; g = 0;   b = 0;   g += x; break;
    case 1: r = 255; g = 255; b = 0;   r -= x; break;
    case 2: r = 0;   g = 255; b = 0;   b += x; break;
    case 3: r = 0;   g = 255; b = 255; g -= x; break;
    case 4: r = 0;   g = 0;   b = 255; r += x; break;
    case 5: r = 255; g = 0;   b = 255; b -= x; break;
    }
    return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            //return rgb value
}
//get red color
uint8_t getRed(uint32_t c) {
    return c >> 16;
}
//get green color
uint8_t getGreen(uint32_t c) {
    return c >> 8;
}
//get blue color
uint8_t getBlue(uint32_t c) {
    return c;
}

//draw 
void draw_gradient(cairo_t *);
static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer user_data)
{             
  draw_gradient(cr);
  return FALSE;
}
void draw_gradient(cairo_t *cr)
{
    int width = 256; //window width
    int height = 50; //window height

    cairo_pattern_t *gradient;
    gradient =cairo_pattern_create_linear(0.0, 0.0,  width, 0.0);

    double range = width;
    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
        uint32_t color = rgb(i / range);//get rgb 

        printf("colors %d | %d %d %d\n", i, getRed(color), getGreen(color), getBlue(color));
        cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient, i, getRed(color), getGreen(color), getBlue(color), 1.0);
    }

    cairo_set_source (cr, gradient);
    cairo_paint (cr);
    cairo_pattern_destroy (gradient);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;  

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), darea);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL);  
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 30); 
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Linear gradients");

  gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(window, TRUE);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}

It only draws a 2 color linear gradient, check the image:


I really don't understand your rgb logic at all.  My advice would be to perform the colour interpretation in a more suitable colour space such as HSV and then convert those values to RGB as/when required.

Sorry.  For colour interpretation please read colour interpolation.

Note that return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b; better as return ((unint32_t)r << 16) | ((unint32_t)g << 8) | b; to handle the case of 16-bit int/unsigned.

@dibyendu, Append the output of printf("colors %d | %d %d %d\n",...

@dibyendu, Given int height = 50; //window height, why is height not used anywhere?  Best to post a [mcve].

@chux - Reinstate Monica,  Window height is not a problem, it's just for testing.
I think the problem is here--
" cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient, i, getRed(color), getGreen(color), getBlue(color), 1.0);"

"It only draws a 2 color linear gradient "is not demonstrated by your code.  Best to post a [mcve].  Lack of height usage is one of many tell-tale signs of the incompleteness of code.

Cairo expects lots of things to be between 0.0 and 1.0, but you are passing in values between 0.0 and 256.0 (the colors) or 0 and width.
Here is a patch that fixes lots of things for me:
--- t.c.orig    2024-06-20 18:01:42.188560553 +0200
+++ t.c 2024-06-20 18:04:05.225964541 +0200
@@ -53,7 +53,7 @@ void draw_gradient(cairo_t *cr)
         uint32_t color = rgb(i / range);//get rgb 
 
         printf("colors %d | %d %d %d\n", i, getRed(color), getGreen(color), getBlue(color));
-        cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient, i, getRed(color), getGreen(color), getBlue(color), 1.0);
+        cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient, i / range, getRed(color) / 256.0, getGreen(color) / 256.0, getBlue(color) / 256.0, 1.0);
     }
 
     cairo_set_source (cr, gradient);


I do not have GTK headers installed and so I made a cairo-only version of your program.
#include <cairo.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t rgb(double ratio)
{
    int normalized = (int)(ratio * 256 * 6);

    //find the region for this position
    int region = normalized / 256;

    //find the distance to the start of the closest region
    int x = normalized % 256;

    uint8_t r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    switch (region)
    {
    case 0: r = 255; g = 0;   b = 0;   g += x; break;
    case 1: r = 255; g = 255; b = 0;   r -= x; break;
    case 2: r = 0;   g = 255; b = 0;   b += x; break;
    case 3: r = 0;   g = 255; b = 255; g -= x; break;
    case 4: r = 0;   g = 0;   b = 255; r += x; break;
    case 5: r = 255; g = 0;   b = 255; b -= x; break;
    }
    return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            //return rgb value
}
//get red color
uint8_t getRed(uint32_t c) {
    return c >> 16;
}
//get green color
uint8_t getGreen(uint32_t c) {
    return c >> 8;
}
//get blue color
uint8_t getBlue(uint32_t c) {
    return c;
}

//draw 
void draw_gradient(cairo_t *cr)
{
    int width = 256; //window width
    int height = 50; //window height

    cairo_pattern_t *gradient;
    gradient =cairo_pattern_create_linear(0.0, 0.0,  width, 0.0);

    double range = width;
    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
        uint32_t color = rgb(i / range);//get rgb 

        printf("colors %d | %d %d %d\n", i, getRed(color), getGreen(color), getBlue(color));
        cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient, i / range, getRed(color) / 256.0, getGreen(color) / 256.0, getBlue(color) / 256.0, 1.0);
    }

    cairo_set_source (cr, gradient);
    cairo_paint (cr);
    cairo_pattern_destroy (gradient);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cairo_surface_t *s = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 256, 50);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(s);
    draw_gradient(cr);
    cairo_surface_write_to_png(s, "gradient.png");
    cairo_surface_destroy(s);
    cairo_destroy(cr);

  return 0;
}

Output: 
This still does not look like what you expect it to look like, but that is a question on where you got the rgb() function from.

Note that this can be greatly simplified. rgb() looks like it has 6 points and just linearly interpolates between those points. You can just let cairo do that for you: Here is a version that produces the same output and does not use your rgb() function.
--- t.c.own 2024-06-20 18:06:27.364129263 +0200
+++ t.c 2024-06-20 18:07:36.103342891 +0200
@@ -47,14 +47,12 @@ void draw_gradient(cairo_t *cr)
     cairo_pattern_t *gradient;
     gradient =cairo_pattern_create_linear(0.0, 0.0,  width, 0.0);
 
-    double range = width;
-    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
-{
-        uint32_t color = rgb(i / range);//get rgb 
-
-        printf("colors %d | %d %d %d\n", i, getRed(color), getGreen(color), getBlue(color));
-        cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient, i / range, getRed(color) / 256.0, getGreen(color) / 256.0, getBlue(color) / 256.0, 1.0);
-    }
+    cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgb (gradient, 0.0 / 5.0, 1, 0, 0);
+    cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgb (gradient, 1.0 / 5.0, 1, 1, 0);
+    cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgb (gradient, 2.0 / 5.0, 0, 1, 0);
+    cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgb (gradient, 3.0 / 5.0, 0, 1, 1);
+    cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgb (gradient, 4.0 / 5.0, 0, 0, 1);
+    cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgb (gradient, 5.0 / 5.0, 1, 0, 1);
 
     cairo_set_source (cr, gradient);
     cairo_paint (cr);


I want to use rgb() function for calculation purpose. Your answer is satisfactory. thanks.
